# what this mean "The Sub procedure performs a task and then returns control to the calling code "

Tags: vb.net

what The Sub procedure performs a task and then returns control to the calling code mean?``

The Sub procedure performs a task and then returns control to the calling code, but it does not return a value to the calling code

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially detailing how a sub routine works.

Sub routines and functions will be execute a block of code, the difference is that a function will return a value whereas a sub will not.

Comment: `the difference is that a function will return a value`, not necessarily, your assumption is they *will return a value*, but they can return `Nothing`...

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this. Let's assume that you have a job to do and you have a bunch of people with specific skills to help you. The job can be broken down into multiple tasks. You are able to perform some of those tasks yourself but some are beyond your abilities so you need to delegate those tasks to your helpers. You are the main method of the application and the tasks you perform are the code in that main method.

When you get to a task that you can't perform, you ask one of your helpers with the appropriate expertise to do it and you wait until they have finished that task before you carry one. Each of your helpers is a method in your application that you can call to perform a specific task.

Some of those helpers will go off and do the task and just come back to you and tell you when they are finished. They are like a `Sub`, i.e. they do a job while you wait but they don't give you anything when they're done.

Some of those helpers will go off and do the task and bring you something back when they are done, e.g. the task might be to go to a shop and buy something or to build something that you need for the next task. They are like a `Function`, i.e. they do the job while you wait and they give you the result of their work when they're done.